# How do I create a shortcut for a python script?

Tags: python

How do I create a shortcut for a python script? I need it to "cd /example/example/example" and "python3 "example.py"

Comment: …or a shell function.  Or an alias.

Answer (score 3):

As @chemicalwill mentioned.  I assume you are on a linux-like system so create a shell script file with a .sh extention. In that file put:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /example/example/example
python3 example.py
```

Then you can either place this .sh file where you want the "shortcut".  If you're using a linux GUI and you want it on your desktop, typically you can place that in `~/Desktop` and it will show up on your desktop.  You will also need to change the file permissions and add the execute bit.  If the .sh file is on your Desktop, use the terminal to cd to your desktop folder and run the following command (where "myshortcut.sh" is the name of your .sh file):

```
chmod a+x myshortcut.sh
```

There are many other options available and some depend on what you're really after.